# have string literal of a windows path, getting SyntaxError: (unicode error)

Tags: python, syntax, escaping

I am looking at building a detection model using cv2 but when I try and print the img_array.shape. I get an error for my file path.

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os  
import cv2
    
data_path = "C:\Users\TomMc\Desktop\Personal_Projects\Python\Dog AI\PetImages"
    
    
categories = ["Dog", "Cat"]
    
    
for category in categories:
    path = os.path.join(data_path, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
        break
    break
    
print(img_array.shape)
```

The error in the console is as follows:

> File "c:\Users\TomMc\Desktop\Personal_Projects\Python\Dog
> AI\OpenAi.py", line 6
> data_path = "C:\Users\TomMc\Desktop\Personal_Projects\Python\Dog AI\PetImages"
>
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes  in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Im not 100% sure what the error is trying to explain.

Comment: The error is for assigning `data_path  = ...`. You need to use forward slashes (`/`), or if you are on Windows you can use backward slashes but you need to escape them: '\\'.

Comment: @wohlstad that woked thankyou. is there a reason why? I just copied the file path should that not still work?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The error is **not** related to printing `img_array.shape`.
As you can see in the error message it refers to ***line 6***:

```
data_path = "C:\Users\TomMc\Desktop\Personal_Projects\Python\Dog AI\PetImages"
```

It is caused by using backward slashes which are used to **escape special characters**.
From [Wikipedia - Escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) (see more info in the link):

> In computing and telecommunication, an escape character is a character
> that invokes an alternative interpretation on the following characters
> in a character sequence.

**In order to fix it you can:**

1. Replace backward slashes with forward ones:

```
data_path = "C:/Users/TomMc/Desktop/Personal_Projects/Python/Dog AI/PetImages"
```

2. If you are using Windows, you can use backward slashes but you need to **escape them**:

```
data_path = "C:\\Users\\TomMc\\Desktop\\Personal_Projects\\Python\\Dog AI\\PetImages"
```